# Mongoose: Pushign to array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema similar to the following:

```
{
  ...
  websites: [
    {
      site_address: String,
      tests: [
        {
          ...
          results: String
          type: String
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to check if `site_address` exists already, if not, create a new entry into `websites` with the given `site_address`.

When `site_address` exists, I want to insert a new object into the `tests` array.

Is there a way to do this all in one command?

Comment: what is your MongoDB version & It would be more helpful with a sample doc & input..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a way of selecting the overall document, yes.  The `update` method will accept an aggregation pipeline as the second argument that will be applied to the matched documents.

There are a few ways this might be accomplished.  One possibility is:
- use `$reduce` to split the websites array into matching and remaining arrays,
- create a stub element if none match, or pull the first element from the match array
- append the new test to the tests array
- append the site element to the remaining array
- remove the temporary fields

```
address="NewString";
testElement={result:"NewString",type:"NewString"}; 
Collection.update({},[
    {$set:{
           match_result:{
                         $reduce:{
                                  input:"$websites",
                                  initialValue:{matched:[],remain:[]},
                                  in: {
                                       matched:{$cond:[{$eq:["$$this.site_address",address]},{$concatArrays:["$$value.matched",["$$this"]]},"$$value.matched"]},
                                       remain:{$cond:[{$ne:["$$this.site_address",address]},{$concatArrays:["$$value.remain",["$$this"]]},"$$value.remain"]},
                                  }
                         }
           }
    }},
    {$set:{
        new_site:{$cond:[{$eq:[{$size:"$match_result.matched"},0]},{site_address:"NewString",tests:[]},{$arrayElemAt:["$match_result.matched",0]}]}
    }},
    {$set: { "new_site.tests":{$concatArrays:["$new_site.tests",[testElement]]}}},
    {$set:{ websites:{$concatArrays:["$match_result.remain",["$new_site"]]}}},
    {$project: {
        match_result:0,
        new_site:0
    }}
])
```

This might end up performing worse than a separate query followed by an update, so some testing should be in order.